# Is it possible to run a macro in Outlook when selection changes?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to run a macro each time I select a message from my Outlook inbox. Ideally, I won't even open the message.

So it would be something like...

*select/highlight email* -> **macro runs** -> *select/highlight next email* -> **macro runs** -> etc.

I can write the macro without issue, but I'm having trouble triggering it. I don't want to push a ribbon button for each email. I know 'selection change' is a macro trigger in Excel but I couldn't find if there's anything similar for Outlook.

In case anyone is curious, the macro will take action depending on the email's contents. But I need it to run based on the emails I select, not the entire inbox.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/api/Outlook.Explorer.SelectionChange

Comment: Well that definitely helped but now I feel like an idiot. Thanks for pointing me to it!